# Powershell: Event in Foreach loop

Tags: powershell

I'm having problems with a `foreach` loop and setting a `Add_MouseClick` event.

Each loop the function generates a new clickable label. While the `.Text` variable setting works as intended, when setting the event listener, it will write out the last generated `$labelName`, regardless of which is clicked.

```
foreach($account in $resUserNameSearchArray){
    #Set form object variables
    $script:labelName = "res" + $i 

    #Form Variable
    Set-Variable -Name $labelName -Value (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label)
    (Get-Variable $labelName -ValueOnly).Text = "$account"
    (Get-Variable $labelName -ValueOnly).Add_MouseClick{  
        Write-Host "$labelName"
    }...
```

There's a few non-relevant lines removed (location, font,etc)

Comment: Here is the rest of the function's code https://pastebin.com/Bx4g2nx7

Comment: Yes, I've been working through it piece by piece. Calling `Write-Host $labelName` outside of the `Add_MouseClick` event works as intended, it appears to only occur when it's wrapped in that event.

Comment: Your click action is going to be evaluated at when you click it. So `$labelname` will be what it is at that moment (the last created), not what it was when the click action was made. So you need to get what label was clicked from inside the mouse click, which I can't think of how to do off the top of my head.

Comment: That got me where I needed! `Write-Host $this.text` did it! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to use `Write-Host $this.text` within the `Add_Click` event to pull in the `.text` of the foreach variable.